# SharePoint file metadata update using GRAPH API PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have to upload file to SharePoint document library and then update file metadata. I am able to upload file but getting error while updating metadata. Here is my code,

```
Param (
    $Tenant = "MY_TENANT_ID",
    $ClientID = "CLIENT_ID",
    $ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRETE",
    $SiteID = "ed34d-3a2f-4ecf-a9c3-1bb8dc1a370a",
    $LibraryURL = "https://xpd396.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/myservicedocs",
    $Path = ".\test.log"
)

#region get access token

$Body = @{
    "client_id" = $ClientID
    "client_secret" = $ClientSecret
    "scope" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    "grant_type" = "client_credentials"
}

#$BodyJSON = $Body | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

$AuthorizationRequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($Tenant).onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $Body -Verbose

#endregion

#region get drives

$Header = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $($AuthorizationRequest.access_token)"
    "Content-Type"= "application/json"
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$SiteID/drives" -Method GET -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/json" -Verbose
$DriveID = $Result.value| Where-Object {$_.webURL -eq $LibraryURL } | Select-Object id -ExpandProperty id

If ($DriveID -eq $null){

    Throw "SharePoint Library under $LibraryURL could not be found."
}

#endregion

#region upload file

$FileName = $Path.Split("\")[-1]
$fileUploadResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/$DriveID/items/root:/$($FileName):/content" -Headers $Header -Method PUT -InFile $Path -ContentType 'multipart/form-data' -Verbose
$fileId = $fileUploadResult.id
#endregion

#region update metadata

$fieldUpdateUrl  = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/$DriveID/items/$fileId"

$fieldUpdateBody = @{
    "Title" = "123"
}

$fieldUpdateBodyJSON = $fieldUpdateBody | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$fileUploadResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $fieldUpdateUrl -Method PATCH -Headers $Header -Body $fieldUpdateBodyJSON
#region
```

I am getting below error while updating metadata.
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to update `field` on the related `listItem`

```
$fieldUpdateUrl  = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/$DriveID/items/$fileId/listItem/fields"
```